# Django - URL design and best practices for identify one object

Tags: django, url, identifier

Im actually working in a django project and I'm not sure about the best format of the URL to access into one particular object page.

I was thinking about these alternatives:

```
1) Using the autoincremental ID => .com/object/15
```

This is the simplest and well known way of do that. "id_object" is the autoincremental ID generated by the database engine while saving the object. The problem I find in this way is that the URLs are simple iterable. So we can make an simple script and visit all the pages by incrementing the ID in the URL. Maybe a security problem.

```
2) Using a <hash_id> => .com/object/c30204225d8311e185c3002219f52617
```

The "hash_id" should be some alphanumeric string value, generated for example with uuid functions. Its a good idea because it is not iterable. But generate "random" uniques IDs may cause some problems.

```
3) Using a Slug => .com/object/some-slug-generated-with-the-object
```

Django comes with a "slug" field for models, and it can be used to identify an object in the URL. The problem I find in this case is that the slug may change in the time, generating broken URLs. If some search engine like Google had indexed this broken URL, users may be guided to "not found" pages and our page rank can decrease. Freezing the Slug can be a solution. I mean, save the slug only on "Add" action, and not in the "Update" one. But the slug can now represent something old or incorrect.

All the options have advantages and disadvantages. May be using some combination of them can some the problems.
What do you think about that?

Comment: Look at url of this question and you will have your answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best option is this:

```
.com/object/AUTOINCREMENT_ID/SLUG_FIELD
```

Why?

**First reason:** the AUTOINCREMENT_ID is simple for the users to identify an object. For example, in an ecommerce site, If the user want to visit several times the page (becouse he's not sure of buying the product) he will recognize the URL.

**Second reason:** The slug field will prevent the problem of someone iterating over the webpage and will make the URL more clear to people.

This `.com/object/10/ford-munstang-2010` is clearer than `.com/object/c30204225d8311e185c3002219f52617`

Comment: That is the best example:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400920/django-url-design-best-practices-for-identify-one-object`

Here they use `/AUTOINCREMENT_ID/SLUG_FIELD`

Comment: In adition, we can solve the problem of iteration by editing the database sequence (in case of PostgreSQL) for example setting an "increment" value of 2 o 3. In this way we generate a sequence with "holes" in the middle, avoiding iterations.
If we don't want that user realize the amount of content we have, we can start the sequence in a random big number and start counting from it.
So, in this way we solve all problems!
Here is the link to sequece edition in PostgreSQL: `http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-altersequence.html`

Comment: Have you tried visiting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400920/some-incorrect-slug-here? They redirect you to the following page (with the correct slug): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400920/django-url-design-best-practices-for-identify-one-object. So, I would use the `id` to identify the resource, and the `slug` to make user friendly urls `;)`

Comment: @Oscar Mederos If any wrong slug (like some-incorrect-slug above) would be recovered if and only if the id part is good, how could a slug prevent iteration over ids if these ones are autoincremented?

Answer (score 2):

IDs are not strictly "iterable". Things get deleted, added back, etc. Over time, there's very rarely a straight linear progression of IDs from 1-1000. From a security perspective, it doesn't really matter. If views need to be protected for some reason, you use logins and only show what each user is allowed to see to each user.

There's upsides and downsides with every approach, but I find slugs to be the best option overall. They're descriptive, they help users know where there at and at a glance enable them to tell where they're going when they click a URL. And, the downsides (404s if slugs change) can be mitigated by 1) don't change slugs, ever 2) set up proper redirects when a slug does need to change for some reason. Django even has a redirects framework baked-in to make that even easier.

The idea of combine an id *and* a slug is just crazy from where I'm sitting. You still rely on either the id *or* the slug part of the URL, so it's inherently no different that using one or the other exclusively. Or, you rely on both and compound your problems and introduce additional points of failure. Using both simply provides no meaningful benefit and seems like nothing more than a great way to introduce headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody talked about the UUID field ([django model field reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)) which can be a good implementation of the "hash id". I think you can have an url like:

```
.com/object/UUID/slug
```

It prevents from showing an order in the URL if this order is not relevant.

Other alternatives could be:

```
.com/object/yyyy-mm-dd/ID/slug
.com/object/kind/ID/slug
```

depending of the relevant information you want to have in the url